# Version/Time of FingerPrint/Face

Tags: biometrics, zkteco, zkemkeeper

We have a few of these units and need to "synchronise" or "replicate" across devices.

We have a program which connects to each of them and collects the data using the functions, GetUserFaceStr and GetUserTmpExStr.

The current flow is to compare the differences between a primary and secondary scanner, and if there's any differences, copy the record on the primary scanner to the secondary scanner. This works to a point.

However we are aware that the scanners are adaptive and the Finger Print templates and Face templates update over time on the scanner, and we have seen this happening.

Is there a way we can get the date or version or the fingerprint or face so that we can always sync the latest versions across?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can´t do that.

I suggest that if you have both Master and Slave devices, just update the slave device with the templates registered on the Master and forget about what is contained on the Slave.

Just force the update every time the Master has any changes.

Best regards.